# Building Caffe CMAKE errors

Tags: ubuntu, git, cmake, caffe

I'm trying to build and install caffe for DIGITS on ubuntu 18.04 , following these steps :

1- `git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/caffe.git`

2- `cd caffe/`

3- `mkdir build && cd build/`

4- `cmake ..`

I get this after running the 4th step :

```
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:567 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:907 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1558 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:5 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:72 (include)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:567 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:907 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1558 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:5 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:72 (include)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:567 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:907 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1558 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:5 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:72 (include)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:567 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:907 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1558 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:5 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:72 (include)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1947 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:5 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:72 (include)


-- Found gflags  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so)
-- Found glog    (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so)
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:455 (message):
  Protobuf compiler version 3.6.1 doesn't match library version 3.0.0
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/ProtoBuf.cmake:4 (find_package)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:24 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:72 (include)


-- Found PROTOBUF Compiler: /home/neox/anaconda3/bin/protoc
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine C configuration
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine CXX configuration
-- Found lmdb    (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.so)
-- Found LevelDB (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libleveldb.so)
-- Found Snappy  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so)
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find JPEGTurbo (missing: JPEGTurbo_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindJPEGTurbo.cmake:18 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:54 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:72 (include)


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory /home/neox/caffe
   used as include directory in directory /home/neox/caffe
   used as include directory in directory /home/neox/caffe

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/neox/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/neox/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

As I understand some of my issues are related to Boost even tho I installed it using :

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

and same for turbojpeg :

```
apt-get install libturbojpeg0-dev
```

but I'm stuck at these errors now .

Comment: Regarding "Protobuf compiler version 3.6.1 doesn't match library version 3.0.0" you can try `sudo apt-get install  protobuf-compiler`.